# Different IntelliJ settings for different projects

Tags: intellij-idea, settings

I have a kind of interesting subject. I am using my IntelliJ IDEA for different projects with different code styles and so on. Is there any kind of setting or switching available for that situation? Because the only thing I can do for now is a script, which changes the link to another IntelliJ settings folder and than runs idea.sh.

Comment: Code styles are already project dependant (see mindreader's answer). If you change the style in one project, other projects won't be affected. So I assume, your `projects` are in fact `modules` within one `project`. In that case, afaik there is no way to set different code styles for different modules within the same project. You should consider moving those modules into separate projects.

Comment: Sure, code styles are already project dependent. But I do not want to reselect them every time when I am changing between different projects.

Comment: You don't need to. Select the scheme `Project` (in `Code Style`) for each of your projects, and the settings are stored separately, without having to switch anything. If you selected your own Scheme ´MyScheme´ instead, then changes to it will be applied to all projects using this scheme (which you don't want).

Comment: found this looking for the same thing for the maven repo settings - I have different local maven repos for my different projects... might have to go with the link option

Answer (score 1):

Different code styles can be defined & chosen from settings menu. You can do so by opening the settings menu (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>) & searching for "code style". Here code styles for individual projects can be added, modified, deleted & renamed. Hope this helps.

Comment: And what about code templates for different projects? I mean different copyright and class or interface description for different projects.

Comment: Copyright settings are also project dependent (like everything that is under `project settings` instead of `IDE settings`). Learn how to assign a copyright profile to a project here: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-copyright-profiles.html